# Accelerometer Z Value off a significant amount, all other values reasonable

Tags: i2c, accelerometer

I'm using the MPU9255 Accelerometer to measure acceleration in the X,Y, and Z directions.  As per the datasheet, I've applied a scaling to the raw digital values based off of whether I specified +- 2G, +- 4G, +- 8G etc.  This scaling works fantastically, but there is consistent noise on the Z axis, far greater than that of gravity's 1G of force.  Here is a sample output

```
ACCELEROMETER-X
0.7226562500
ACCELEROMETER-Y
0.1523437500    
ACCELEROMETER-Z
7.9707031250    

ACCELEROMETER-X
0.7460937500
ACCELEROMETER-Y
0.1875000000    
ACCELEROMETER-Z
8.0468750000
```

As you can see, there is about 7G of noise on the Z axis. I calculated the scaling with this code:

```
//Get accelerometer scaling based off of how many G's per of variation the system was tuned to handle
int16_t getAccScalar(int16_t system_scale){
  int16_t acc_scalar = 16384;
  short scalar = 1;
  if(system_scale == ACC_FULL_SCALE_4_G){
    scalar = 2;
  }
  else if(system_scale == ACC_FULL_SCALE_8_G){
    scalar = 4;
  }
  else{
    scalar = 8;
  }
  acc_scalar /= scalar;
  return acc_scalar;
}
```

And then in configuration I use a register writing function with this header:

```
void I2CwriteByte(uint8_t Address, uint8_t Register, uint8_t Data)
```

and call it with these values

```
I2CwriteByte(MPU9250_ADDRESS,28,ACC_FULL_SCALE_2_G);
```

Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks and have a squanchy day.

Comment: I suspect are just looking at the 1G from gravity and your scaling is off; What happens when you turn the accelerometer on its side?

Comment: When you turn the accelerometer on its side, all the force transfers to the other axis as expected.  But here's the thing, the scaling I'm using is perfect scaling for X and Y, so why is Z so far off? It's the same scaling for all 3 axes.

Comment: The accelerometer scaling value was off from the one that I set as the actual scaling, so scaling was indeed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accelerometer static errors are usually not anywhere near that large, so I suspect your scaling code is not behaving correctly. You could verify this by turning the accelerometer on its side and see if the Z axis retains a +7G value, or if the X/Y axis instead becomes too large.